# How do I add options on my discord.py v2.1 bot with slash commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a few moderation commands in my bot, which is on v2.1 of discord.py (not Pycord), but I am having trouble getting the options.

I have a command so far, like this:

```
@commands.command(name="ban")
  @commands.bot_has_guild_permissions(ban_members=True)
  async def ban(self, interacton: discord.Interaction, member: (discord.Member), reason: (str, required = False) = None):
    """[Mod] Bans the specified member, with an optional reason."""
    if member.top_role > ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.send('This member has a role higher than your\'s, so I can\'t do that.')
    elif member == member.id(791667264235634729):
        await ctx.send('Why the heck do you want to ban me? I didn\'t do anything! ;-;')
    elif member.top_role == ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.send('That member has the same rank as you, therefore I cannot ban them.') 
    elif member == ctx.author:
        await ctx.send('You cannot ban yourself! I do not condone that behaviour.')
    else:
        if reason == None:
            await member.ban(reason=f'Banned by {ctx.author}, with no reason specified.')
            await ctx.send(f'{member} was sucessfully banned')
        else:
            await member.ban(reason=f'Banned by {ctx.author} | {reason}')
            await ctx.send(f'{member} was sucessfully banned | {reason}')
```

However, as far as I know, the "Option(x)" argument is probably more for Pycord, but I want to use the latest discord.py instead, and I need to know how I can add options (member, reason etc) with a ban command for example.

Answer (score 0):

all u need to do is to remove the "(" ")" from member and to change the reson to be None for making it a Not required arg and remove the required = False
from

```
async def ban(self, interacton: discord.Interaction, member: (discord.Member), reason: (str, required = False) = None):
```

to

```
async def ban(self, interacton: discord.Interaction, member:discord.Member, reason:str = None):
```